# KAFKA 1.0 - Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Getting below error as consumer to kafka topic. Publisher has to use gzip compression then publish to kafka due to file size exceeding 70mb with out prior gzip. As an when consumer tries to read kafka, below error shows up. any sugestions?

```
10:56:26,082 [pool-13-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher: Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition testKafka-0
WARN  2018-04-13 10:56:26,125 [pool-13-thread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher: Unknown error fetching data for topic-partition testKafka-0
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, i found kafka-client(consumer) version is different  than others. Please verify your client version and make it similar/same everywhere. Example : if you are using client version 0.11.0.0 then cross verify is this is same across the project.